# How to show the congruence involving the order

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If $\alpha$ is the lower positive integer such as $x^{\alpha}\equiv 1\mod m$ and the order of $x$  in modulus $m$ is define by $\alpha = \textrm{ord}_{m} x$

Prove that :

$$a \cdot b \equiv 1\mod m \Longrightarrow \textrm{ord}_{m}a = \textrm{ord}_{m}b$$

I have no idea how to start it!!

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Suppose $\textrm{ord}_m a = r$ and $\textrm{ord}_m b = s$; then $a\cdot b\equiv 1\mod m$ implies that $a^rb^r\equiv 1\mod m$, so that $b^r\equiv 1\mod m$. What does that tell you about $r$ as it relates to $s=\textrm{ord}_m b$? Now repeat the process, raising both sides to $s$.

Comment: It means that $r$ = $\text{ord}_{m}b$ by the definition?

Comment: No, not quite. $\textrm{ord}_m b$ is the *smallest* integer $q$ such that $b^q\equiv 1\mod m$; $r$ is just some such integer.

Comment: True! So when you say repeat the process raising both sides to $\text{ord}_{m} b $ is that $(a \cdot b)^{ord_{m} b} \equiv 1$ (mod $m$) is this what you mean..

Comment: Yes, that's right. Can you finish the proof from there?

Comment: i can not finish it, but ill try..

Comment: So explicitly, how are $r$ and $\textrm{ord}_m b$ related?

Comment: well they are related by $x^{r} \equiv 1 $ mod$m$

Comment: $s=\textrm{ord}_m b$ is the *smallest* positive integer with $b^s\equiv 1\mod m$. $r$ is *some* positive integer with $b^r\equiv 1\mod m$. So how are $r$ and $s$ related? Do they need to be equal? Can they be equal? If not, which one is larger?

Comment: If they are equal the prove is done and if they are not equal $r$ is bigger that  $s$ because $s$ is the smallest positive integer such as  $b^s\equiv 1\mod m$

Comment: Great. So you've shown that $r\ge s$. Now go back to my answer: repeat this process, starting with $ab\equiv 1\mod m$, and raise both sides to the $s$ power. What does *that* tell you about how $r$ and $s$ are related?

Comment: Usderstood!! From this part we have that $r \geq s$ and if i go back and repeat the process ill get that $ s \geq r$ there for $r = s$ an its done.

Comment: Indeed. Gotta love that Aha! moment.

Comment: Jajaj it was great!!! Thats for help me!! And thanks for not show the complete answer!!!!